# newgeometry shifting content vertically

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, geometry

I'm having an issue with the geometry package. After assigning a `\newgeometry` mid-document my page content shifts vertically.I'm aware that `\newgeometry` 'disables all the options specified in the preamble' but I'm almost giving the `\newgeometry` the same variables as `geometry` in the preamble (I'm using a `.sty` file for my settings). Here are my document in a mws'ish fashion:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[left=24mm,right=14mm,top=18mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{strucrep}
    \makeoddhead{strucrep}{\small
        \begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{@{}l X r | l r}
            \textbf{Sag:}   & & Building 231 & \textbf{Dok. dato:} & 2017-05-21 \\
            \textbf{Sags nr.:}  & & A-2341  & \textbf{Rev. dato:} & 2017-05-28 \\
            \textbf{Doc. ID:} & & K09\_B2.2 &\textbf{Revision:}  & A \\
            \multicolumn{3}{@{}l |}{\textbf{A. Konstruktionsdokumentation}} &\textbf{Side:} & \thepage \\
            \multicolumn{4}{@{}l }{\Large\textbf{A1. Projektgrundlag}}  & \rule{0pt}{6mm} \\
        \end{tabularx}
    }{}{}
\setlength{\headheight}{32mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{8mm}

\pagestyle{strucrep}

\newcommand\BackgroundPicture{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
    \put(10, 10){\framebox(192,247){}}
}

\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}

\begin{document}

\section{\TeX}
\lipsum
\newpage

\ClearShipoutPicture

\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}
\newgeometry{left=24mm, right=44mm, top=18mm, bottom=40mm, marginparsep=10mm, marginparwidth=20mm}
\edef\marginnotetextwidth{\the\textwidth}
\section{\LaTeX}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It produces the following correct header:
[image: correct header]

And after the `\newgeometry` it produces this incorrect heading:
[image: Incorrect heading]

I've tried repeating the `\setlength{\headheight}` and `\setlength{\headsep}` command after the `\newgeometry`, to no avail.

I guess I could just set `top=XXmm` to force it down to the correct position, however I'd really like to know how to fix it in a way I understand.

Comment: Don't change geometry lengths like `\headheight` and `\headsep` after setting up the geometry using `geometry`. `geometry` provides options for these!

Comment: Hi @Schweinebacke. Thank you so much, you've helped me figure it out! As per default in geometry my header was not 'included' and hence it had to reside in the 'top', which I'd only given 18mm. Somehow my setlengths had fixed it for the initial geometry.  

Edit: Oops, enter = post... 
So I set the headheight and headsep in the geometry like you suggested and expanded 'top'. I did it in geometry and newgeometry, and the problem is solved. Again thank you.  

Edit: added tag

Comment: Can you add an answer (not as part of your question but a real answer)? Yes, self-answering is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as pointed out by @Schweinebacke, was that I used `\setlength` after defining geometry, this fixed an incorrectly defined geometry.

The correct way is to define the 'top' to include the header (and headsep and headheight) and define `headheight` and `headsep` in the definition of geometry. This has to be done in both `geometry` and `\newgeometry`.

So the correct way would be:

```
\usepackage[left=24mm,right=14mm,top=40mm,bottom=40mm, headheight=32mm, headsep=8mm]{geometry}
```

and

```
\newgeometry{left=24mm, right=44mm, top=40mm, bottom=40mm, marginparsep=10mm, marginparwidth=20mm, headheight=32mm, headsep=8mm}
```

(You can include the header in the text-area using `includehead`, but I like this way more)

Thanks to @Schweinebacke